# Match beginning of a line and beginning of remain line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm trying come up with syntax highlighter that would match beginning of the line (timestamp) and then beginning of the remaining line.
For example:

```
12:34:56.789 some1 text some2 other text
some3 text some4 other text
```

I need to capture words `some` but only if it's at the beginning of the text, ignoring timestamp. So in this example they are `some1` and `some3`

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
  "name": "my-output",
  "scopeName": "source.my_output",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "begin": "^(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3,}\\s)?",
      "end": "$",
      "beginCaptures":{
        "1": {"name": "my-output-date"}
      },
      "patterns": [
        
        {
          "match": "^(some\\d)",
          "captures":{
            "1": {"name": "my-output-red"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is beginning of the line may start with a timestamp `12:34:56.789` so in this example it only captures `some3`

If I remove `^` from the regex: `"match": "(some\\d)"` it captures all 4 words instead.

Does vscode provide ability split text into chunks and process each chunk as whole text (where we could use `^` and `$` on the chunk)?

Comment: Perhaps like this `"match": "^(?:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3,}\\s)?(some\\d)",`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's one way I'm trying to avoid, because there are several dozens of keywords and I'm trying make it less cumbersome without duplications...

Comment: Then perhaps you might use `([^\\d\\s]+\\d)` to start the match with non digits followed by digits?

Comment: The problem is without `^` it might capture in the middle of the string and it seems `^` is not allowed in the nested pattern. For example `^.*` will not match anything if parent pattern matched something.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution: use [`\G`](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE#L182) anchor (beginning of text after last match):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
  "name": "my-output",
  "scopeName": "source.my_output",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "begin": "^(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3,}\\s)?",
      "end": "$",
      "beginCaptures":{
        "1": {"name": "my-output-date"}
      },
      "patterns": [
        
        {
          "match": "\\G(some\\d)",
          "captures":{
            "1": {"name": "my-output-red"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, there is seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162626) where it skips a line if previous line is empty. For now, my fix is to replace `"end": "$"` regex with: `"end": "\\r?\\n"`